# StackWise Virtual Issue on 9500 (network-advantage)

Tags: cisco

I need to configure StackWise Virtual b/w my switches (Cat9500s) but the command just doesn't appear and I dont know why. They are just out of box switches, turned on a few hours earlier.

Only stack* commands I have:

```
Switch(config)#stack?
stack-mac  stackmaker  stacks
```

some useful output:

```
Switch Ports Model              SW Version        SW Image              Mode   
------ ----- -----              ----------        ----------            ----   
*    1 50    C9500-40X          16.6.4            CAT9K_IOSXE           INSTALL



Switch#sh license right-to-use detail 
    Index 1
      License Name    : network-essentials
      Period left     : Lifetime
      License Type    : Permanent
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 2
      License Name    : network-essentials
      Period left     : 90
      License Type    : Evaluation
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 3
      License Name    : network-essentials
      Period left     : Not Active
      License Type    : Subscription
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 4
      **License Name    : network-advantage
      Period left     : Lifetime
      License Type    : Permanent
      License State   : Active, In use
      License Location: Slot 1**
    Index 5
      License Name    : network-advantage
      Period left     : 90
      License Type    : Evaluation
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 6
      License Name    : network-advantage
      Period left     : Not Active
      License Type    : Subscription
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 7
      License Name    : dna-essentials
      Period left     : 90
      License Type    : Evaluation
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 8
      License Name    : dna-essentials
      Period left     : Not Active
      License Type    : Subscription
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 9
      License Name    : dna-advantage
      Period left     : 90
      License Type    : Evaluation
      License State   : Not Activated
      License Location: Slot 1
    Index 10
      License Name    : dna-advantage
      Period left     : CSSM Managed
      License Type    : Subscription
      License State   : Active, In use
      License Location: Slot 1

Switch#sh ver
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.06.04
Cisco IOS Software [Everest], Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT9K_IOSXE), Version 16.6.4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change license

```
license boot level network-advantage addon dna-advantage
```

Answer (score 1):

On Cisco IOS XE Everest 16.6.x, Cisco StackWise Virtual is only supported on C9500-24Q switch models.

Also on the Cisco C9500-24Q all the switches in the Cisco StackWise Virtual solution should be running the same license level.

Source:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9500/software/release/16-6/configuration_guide/b_166_ha_9500/b_166_ha_9500_chapter_01.pdf

Under **Restrictions for Cisco StackWise Virtual**

Answer (score 0):

Correct ; The license should be 
license boot level network-advantage addon dna-essentials
license smart transport callhome